# IP address remapping

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip-address

I don't know how exactly to formulate my question but i will try to explain what i am asking for.

I have a firm that developes gps devices and each device is beeing put on a separate vehicle. The devices' firmware have hardcoded IP adress that they send the current data to.

I have a server at the firm that accepts the data from the devices. However the bussiness is growing and i don't want to risk using it. That is why i'm thinking about moving the server's software to amazon EC2.

Before doing that i want to know if it is possible to use my current IP adress on the amazon EC2 service because there is NO way to change the IP address that is hardcoded on the devices'firmware.

So let's summarize the situation.

- A <-- Gps device with firmware that sends data to address x.y.z.w
- B <-- Server with special software that accepts data from A. The server IP is x.y.z.w
- C <-- Amazon EC2 service with IP address: a.b.c.d

I want to get rid of server B. So A ->> sends data to ->> server C.

How to congigure server C so that it uses the ip address of server B (having in mind that server C is in different county with different Ip address range ) ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do, keep in mind that I don't know the details of what kind of connection is made.

The hard coded IP Address would map to a load balancer/proxy at your site/datacenter. This will balance traffic between one or more servers either at your site or on ec2 which runs the software for your application.

For high availability purposes, I would configure a heartbeat monitor on the load balancer to fail over to a backup load balancer should it fail.

You still have a failure point in that it would be difficult to redirect traffic to another site should your site go down.